# How to fix "Undefined offset: 1", exception: "ErrorException"?

Tags: php, laravel

My Html Code

```
<div class="businessHours-input">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <th>Week Days</th>
                <th>Opening Time</th>
                <th>Closing Time</th>
                <th>Open 24 hours</th>
                <th>Close</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <input type="text" name="weekday[1]" href="1"  id="weekday1" class="form-control" value="Saturday">
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <select name="opening_time[1]" class="opening_time" href="1" id="opening_time1">
                      <option value="">Choose</option>
                      @if ($range = range(strtotime('00:00'),strtotime('23:59'),30*60))
                        @foreach ($range as $time)
                          <option value="{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}">{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      @endif
                    </select>
                    <span value="1" class="editOpening">Edit</span>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <select name="closing_time[1]" class="closing_time" href="1" id="closing_time1">
                      <option value="">Choose</option>
                      @if ($range = range(strtotime('00:00'),strtotime('23:59'),30*60))
                        @foreach ($range as $time)
                          <option value="{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}">{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      @endif
                    </select>
                    <span value="1" class="editClosing">Edit</span>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <label for="always1"><input type="checkbox" name="always[1]" value="always" class="alwaysOpen" href="1" id="always1"> 24Hours</label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <label for="close1"><input type="checkbox" name="close[1]" class="closeBiz" value="close" href="1" id="close1"> Close</label>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <input type="text" name="weekday[2]" href="2"  id="weekday2" class="form-control" value="Sunday">
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <select name="opening_time[2]" class="opening_time" href="2" id="opening_time2">
                      <option value="">Choose</option>
                      @if ($range = range(strtotime('00:00'),strtotime('23:59'),30*60))
                        @foreach ($range as $time)
                          <option value="{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}">{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      @endif
                    </select>
                    <span value="2" class="editOpening">Edit</span>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <select name="closing_time[2]" class="closing_time" href="2" id="closing_time2">
                      <option value="">Choose</option>
                      @if ($range = range(strtotime('00:00'),strtotime('23:59'),30*60))
                        @foreach ($range as $time)
                          <option value="{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}">{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      @endif
                    </select>
                    <span value="2" class="editClosing">Edit</span>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <label for="always2"><input type="checkbox" name="always[2]" value="always" class="alwaysOpen" href="2" id="always2"> 24Hours</label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <label for="close2"><input type="checkbox" name="close[2]" class="closeBiz" value="close" href="2" id="close2"> Close</label>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <input type="text" name="weekday[3]" href="3"  id="weekday3" class="form-control" value="Monday">
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <select name="opening_time[3]" class="opening_time" href="3" id="opening_time3">
                      <option value="">Choose</option>
                      @if ($range = range(strtotime('00:00'),strtotime('23:59'),30*60))
                        @foreach ($range as $time)
                          <option value="{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}">{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      @endif
                    </select>
                    <span value="3" class="editOpening">Edit</span>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <select name="closing_time[3]" class="closing_time" href="3" id="closing_time3">
                      <option value="">Choose</option>
                      @if ($range = range(strtotime('00:00'),strtotime('23:59'),30*60))
                        @foreach ($range as $time)
                          <option value="{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}">{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      @endif
                    </select>
                    <span value="3" class="editClosing">Edit</span>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <label for="always3"><input type="checkbox" name="always[3]" value="always" class="alwaysOpen" href="3" id="always3"> 24Hours</label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <label for="close3"><input type="checkbox" name="close[3]" class="closeBiz" value="close" href="3" id="close3"> Close</label>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <input type="text" name="weekday[4]" href="4"  id="weekday4" class="form-control" value="Tuesday">
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <select name="opening_time[4]" class="opening_time" id="opening_time4">
                      <option value="">Choose</option>
                      @if ($range = range(strtotime('00:00'),strtotime('23:59'),30*60))
                        @foreach ($range as $time)
                          <option value="{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}">{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      @endif
                    </select>
                    <span value="4" class="editOpening">Edit</span>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <select name="closing_time[4]" class="closing_time" href="4" id="closing_time4">
                      <option value="">Choose</option>
                      @if ($range = range(strtotime('00:00'),strtotime('23:59'),30*60))
                        @foreach ($range as $time)
                          <option value="{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}">{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      @endif
                    </select>
                    <span value="4" class="editClosing">Edit</span>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <label for="always4"><input type="checkbox" name="always[4]" value="always" class="alwaysOpen" href="4" id="always4"> 24Hours</label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <label for="close4"><input type="checkbox" name="close[4]" class="closeBiz" value="close" href="4" id="close4"> Close</label>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <input type="text" name="weekday[5]" href="5"  id="weekday5" class="form-control" value="Wednesday">
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <select name="opening_time[5]" class="opening_time" href="5" id="opening_time5">
                      <option value="">Choose</option>
                      @if ($range = range(strtotime('00:00'),strtotime('23:59'),30*60))
                        @foreach ($range as $time)
                          <option value="{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}">{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      @endif
                    </select>
                    <span value="5" class="editOpening">Edit</span>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <select name="closing_time[5]" class="closing_time" href="5" id="closing_time5">
                      <option value="">Choose</option>
                      @if ($range = range(strtotime('00:00'),strtotime('23:59'),30*60))
                        @foreach ($range as $time)
                          <option value="{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}">{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      @endif
                    </select>
                    <span value="5" class="editClosing">Edit</span>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <label for="always5"><input type="checkbox" name="always[5]" value="always" class="alwaysOpen" href="5" id="always5"> 24Hours</label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <label for="close5"><input type="checkbox" name="close[5]" class="closeBiz" value="close" href="5" id="close5"> Close</label>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <input type="text" name="weekday[6]" href="6"  id="weekday6" class="form-control" value="Thursday">
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <select name="opening_time[6]" class="opening_time" href="6" id="opening_time6">
                      <option value="">Choose</option>
                      @if ($range = range(strtotime('00:00'),strtotime('23:59'),30*60))
                        @foreach ($range as $time)
                          <option value="{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}">{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      @endif
                    </select>
                    <span value="6" class="editOpening">Edit</span>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <select name="closing_time[6]" class="closing_time" href="6" id="closing_time6">
                      <option value="">Choose</option>
                      @if ($range = range(strtotime('00:00'),strtotime('23:59'),30*60))
                        @foreach ($range as $time)
                          <option value="{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}">{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      @endif
                    </select>
                    <span value="6" class="editClosing">Edit</span>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <label for="always6"><input type="checkbox" name="always[6]" value="always" class="alwaysOpen" href="6" id="always6"> 24Hours</label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <label for="close6"><input type="checkbox" name="close[6]" class="closeBiz" value="close" href="6" id="close6"> Close</label>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <input type="text" name="weekday[7]" href="7"  id="weekday7" class="form-control" value="Friday">
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <select name="opening_time[7]" class="opening_time" href="7" id="opening_time7">
                      <option value="">Choose</option>
                      @if ($range = range(strtotime('00:00'),strtotime('23:59'),30*60))
                        @foreach ($range as $time)
                          <option value="{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}">{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      @endif
                    </select>
                    <span value="7" class="editOpening">Edit</span>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour" id="closebizHour7">
                    <select name="closing_time[7]" class="closing_time" href="7" id="closing_time7">
                      <option value="">Choose</option>
                      @if ($range = range(strtotime('00:00'),strtotime('23:59'),30*60))
                        @foreach ($range as $time)
                          <option value="{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}">{{ date('h:i A',$time) }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      @endif
                    </select>
                    <span value="7" class="editClosing">Edit</span>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <label for="always7"><input type="checkbox" name="always[7]" value="always" class="alwaysOpen" href="7" id="always7"> 24Hours</label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="per-input per-businessHour">
                    <label for="close7"><input type="checkbox" name="close[7]" class="closeBiz" value="close" href="7" id="close7"> Close</label>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
```

My laravel code to upload

```
foreach ($request->weekday as $key => $weekday) {
                $proBusiness = new ProBusinessHour;
                $proBusiness->pro_listing_id = $proListing->id;
                $proBusiness->weekday = $weekday;
                if (($request->opening_time[$key] && $request->closing_time[$key]) == null) {
                    if ($request->close[$key] == 'close') {
                        $proBusiness->close = 1;
                    } else {
                        if ($request->always[$key] == 'always') {
                            $proBusiness->always = 1;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (($request->opening_time[$key] && $request->closing_time[$key]) == null && $request->always[$key] == 'always') {
                        $proBusiness->always = 1;
                    } else {
                        $proBusiness->opening_time = $request->opening_time[$key];
                        $proBusiness->closing_time = $request->closing_time[$key];
                    }


                }
                $proBusiness->save();
            }
```

Problem is described below:

- There has 7 days. If any days don't have an opening time and closing time and have close value or always value. In that case, it needs to upload close or always status
- If have always value in all days except one and has close value. In that case, it needs to upload always status in all days except on which have close value and upload close status in that day

*** Sometimes it returns

```
"Undefined offset: 1", exception: "ErrorException"
```

How to solve this issue?? I can't solve this, is there any mistake in laravel code? Can anyone help me to solve this issue, please!

Comment: This exception is thrown when you try to access an key of an array which doesn't exist, in this case `1`. So I'd suggest to put a check where you are accessing array with index, eg. `$request->opening_time[$key]` but preceding a check `isset($request->opening_time[$key])` in every occurrences.

Comment: everything is ok.. but when all day check always option and one day checked close option at that time it returns an error that undefined offset...always option will update to the database but close option not and shows error like undefined offset 1/7.  @maksbd19

Comment: Could you take a screenshot of the error screen and post it here?

Comment: I am doing it in ajax

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. Its worked when I try to do with isset @maksbd19